# how to change typehead template structure based on ajax response

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-typeahead

i am using bootstrap-typehead.js for auto-complete feature, and its working fine.

```
    $('#input-toggle').typeahead({
            name: 'user',
            template:['<div class="media br-bottom">',
                      '<a class="pull-left" href="#"><img width="30px" height="30px" class="media-object img-rounded" src="{{avatar}}"></a>',
                      '<div class="media-body"><h4 class="media-heading">{{name}}</h4>',
                      '<p>{{location}}<p></div></div>'
                      ].join(''),
            engine: Hogan,

            remote: ajaxurl+'?action=search_user_tag&q=%QUERY&post_id='+post_id,
        });
```

now i want to change the template structure based on ajax response.
how can i do it?

Comment: What have you already tried? Can you show us?

Comment: the problem is where should i implement my logic to change the template structure, because above code takes care of all logic itself. and i cant apply if-else logic here.

Comment: If you are trying to change the structure according to the data received it would be better if you take out the template from the ajax call and call the data source file from the ajax call and put the template in the html file.